# SQL Server 2016 InitializeExternalUserGroupSid failed message on startup

Tags: sql-server-2016, error-log

I have a SQL Server 2016 installation that I inherited. It does not use or have R or Machine Learning configured. When it starts, I see these messages in the log:

> InitializeExternalUserGroupSid failed. Implied authentication will be
> disabled.
>
> Implied authentication manager initialization failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.

Are these normal and expected or do they indicate a problem?